# Is there any way to Read & Update appSettings.json file from any controller method to save usersettings in ASP.NET Core 2 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I tried many tricks from StackOverflow to Save & Update appSettings.json file but nothing working. Some snippets working only in Startup.cs only for read appSettings.json not for updating. Please help!

Comment: You should show what you've tried that didn't work

Comment: Are you sure you want to store user settings in appSettings.json in an MVC application? Does your app have only a single user?

Comment: If you find yourself needing to update appSettings then you should stop and consider another means of data storage. There is a reason everyone who tries this ends up at stackoverflow - it just is not an appropriate approach.

Comment: @AdamSimon I want to store some keys for admin usage like 
External login keys,
Admin email which receive notification,
Mail Server Settings
`These all will be changeable at runtime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's a bad idea to persist user settings into appsettings.json. The OS process executing your MVC app should never have write permission to this file for security reasons.

I would probably use a DB engine with ACID capabilities for this purpose. However, it could be ok to store such user settings in the file system - but in a separate file, at a safe location.

For example I'd create a folder named say App_Data in the application root folder, set write permission to it and place an adminsettings.json file into it. Then I'd use this file as my persistent storage for the said user settings.

Obviously, it would require some coding to make all this work. I put together [a code sample](https://gist.github.com/adams85/0b5192e81ff8eb89fc6d258c14a43761) for you which aims to reuse the configuration and options API of .NET Core. I think it exceeds the size acceptable here, so I made it available as a Gist.